# Building real time commenting feature

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, forms

I am trying to add real time comment feature to all posts user timeline page.
Here is what i have done:

All Posts contain comment section having following html form:

```
<form action="#" class='post-comment' data-id='3214'>
    <input type="text" name='comment'>
    <input type='submit' style='visibility: hidden;'>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript code which handles the form submit event:

```
 $(".post-comment").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log('Comment on: '+id);
    var dbref = firebase.database().ref('post-user/'+id+'/comments');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var t = Date.now();
    dbref.push().set({
      postedAt: t,
      text:data.comment,
      pid:id
    });
})
```

After making some input as comment when user presses the enter key then the web page reloads instead of invoking function in Javascript.

I want to get comment data and corresponding post details(id,authorid) and send comment data to firebase on enter key press.

After doing some searches i came to know about key press events as below:

```
 $("input").keypress(function(event) {
     if (event.which == 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

But in this case i have multiple forms that is every post contains corresponding comment form so i am confused how to implement this here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use ASP.Net SignalR

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i am using firebase in android app and also want to use same here in web.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an `id`:

```
<form id='comment-form' action="#" class='post-comment' data-id='3214'>
```

Then submit just that form:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#comment-form").submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: But since I have multiple forms corresponding to each post, so how would I get form element in  $("#comment-form").submit();

Comment: @flamelite forget about the form. Use only one `input` - add a `keyPress event on key 13 (Enter)` as shown by @Frank and for every Enter, call your firebase posting function. ex: `dbref.set($("input").value)` -> make sure you set to the proper key. You need to **keep track of the first Enter press**. `let myFKey == null; if myFKey == null then myFKey = dbred.push().key and then in same if branch, set the value - > else just set the value for the already existing myFKey`. This prevents creating multiple records in your firebase. And take a look at firestore. Maybe you like it better.

Comment: `$("#comment-form")` gets the correct form by its id.

Comment: @alon yeah thanks for the idea, i am doing that only right now :) Soon i will update my code if it works.